# How to install jogl in NetBeans?

Tags: java, opengl, download, jogl

I would like to make the game in java in OpenGL, but... how to install JOGL in NetBeans? I can't find link to download this.
Do I need to install it?

Answer (score 6):

Latest sources seem to be [here](http://kenai.com/projects/jogl/sources/jogl-git/show)

jogl doesn't seem to have much activity. Maybe you would be better of using [lwjgl](http://lwjgl.org/)

Comment: JOGL is pretty terrible anyway. If you're making a game, you want a game engine.

Comment: Been there, done that. Many times. Avoid JOGL. Many issues related.